# Radio Buttons Do Not Updates the Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use radio buttons for survey.
ex:

- Best Article Award: Tamil   Monica
- Best Article on Travelogue Award: Tamil  Selvi

The answers will be the radio buttons and I am implementing this as follows:

```
<%=radio_button(count, :voting, :nominees ) %> <%= response.nomination %>
```

Where count is the id of radio button

- voting -- model name
- nominees -- attribute name
- response.nomination -- option value

This gives the above result but the selected values are not updating in the nominees field. Can anyone tell were I am wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Ok then try this

```
<%=radio_button(:voting, :nominees, :id=>count, :value=>response.nomination)%>
```

Comment: <% count = 1 %>
<% for question in @questions %>
<%=count%>. <%= question.title if question.title%>          
     <% for response in @response %>       
          <% if response.question_id.eql?(question.id) %>
 <%=radio_button(count, :voting, :nominees) %> <%= response.nomination %> <% end %> <% end %>
             <% count += 1 %>  <% end %>
 This is my whole code to implment the survey. if i give the count as third argument in radio button i cant select  answer for each question. i can select only one answer for the whole survey.

Comment: Also if i give the value inside radio_button, no values are displayed

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<%=radio_button(count, :voting, @response.nomination)%>
```

and what does **:nominees** you have used

Comment: Actually i want to store the selected values in nominees field.(its a attribute in voting model)..
Also am getting the option values from reponse table.( response.nomination )